# Making Multiple rows into column in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a source table that have values like shown

[image: source table]

i want the output to be like this

[image: target table]

i tried many things but to no avail.

is there anyway to do this using the infromatica developer client?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to join first `C41` with first `C42`, etc. - as you did not mention how to deremine which of the numerical rows should get tied to `IN`.

Looks like you need to generate sequence for each `Field_Name`, split the data flow into two, based on `Field_Name`, and join back using the generated sequence.

The Expression should generate a sequence by having following ports:

```
(variable port) v_seq = IIF(prev_Field_Name = Field_Name, v_seq+1, 1)
(variable port) prev_Field_Name = Field_Name
(output port)   out_seq = v_seq
```

Now the flow would be like this:

```
Src--SQ--Exp_generate_seq--RTR--(C41)-\
                              \-(C42)--Jnr_by_seq
```